# No section wrapping in UICollectionView

Tags: layout, ios6, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView to display cells but I would like to change the default wrapping behaviour in the sections. I don't want any wrapping, instead, I would like  the equivalent of a variable width horizontal scrollview for each section, like shown in the following image.
[image]

I can do this using horizontal scrollviews within a vertical scrollview but I would like to use a collection view. Any idea on how to do this with a custom flow layout maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this to work? Why not a colletionview of collectionviews (stick 1 row collectionviews inside a multirow collectionview). Or a tableview with each cell being a colletionview of 1 row? Or single row colletionviews inside a scrollview?

Comment: I got it working with horizontal scrollviews within a vertical scrollview. But I still would prefer using a collection view with all the memory management reflexes. I put this on the back burner for now but I stay on the lookout.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest collection views, but you have to be careful separating their delegates to avoid having one collection view being affected by a call to the other.

Create the first collection view with vertical scrolling and as many sections you like. Its delegate must be the controller view it is embedded in. Subclass its cell.

Inside the first collection view's cell create a second collection view with horizontal scrolling. Its delegate is the cell of the first collection view.

You can find an example here: [Issue with nested UICollectionViews](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13741706/2252465)

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. I got it working by embedding the collection views within the cells of a tableview - one horizontally scrolling collection view per cell. Works great. I guess playing with flows of  single collection view would have worked too but I had other requirements.