# Issue with nested UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 2 nested UICollectionViews. The delegate for the outer collection view is the main view controller, and the inner collection views delegate is the UICollectionCell of the outer collection view.

The outer collection view has only a label and the inner collection view in it - normally there would be seven of these, the inner collection view should contain 3 or 4 cells (containing 3 labels).

The problem is that the inner collection view only seems to get updated twice (for the first 2 sets of data in the outer views) after that they repeat.

Here is the cellForItemAtIndexPath for the outer UICollectionView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Main Tide Data Table Cell";

    TideDataTableCell* tideDayDataCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tideDayDataCell.tideDataTable.delegate = tideDayDataCell;
    tideDayDataCell.tideDataTable.dataSource = tideDayDataCell;
    tidalDate* tideDate = self.tidalDates[indexPath.row];
    tideDayDataCell.thisTidalDate = tideDate;
    tideDayDataCell.dayLabel.text = tideDate.dateString;
    tideDayDataCell.averageTideHeight = self.avgTideHeight;

    tideDayDataCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return tideDayDataCell;
}
```

... and here is the cellForItemAtIndexPath for the second UICollectionView which is in the UICollectionViewCell object for the out UICollection view!

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Tide Info Table Cell";

    TidalTideTableCell* tidalTideTableCell = [self.tideDataTable dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tidalTideTableCell.timeTideLabel.text = @"";
    tidalTideTableCell.heightTideLabel.text = @"";
    tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"";
    self.tideDataTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Tide* tide = self.thisTidalDate.tides[indexPath.row];
    tidalTideTableCell.heightTideLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tide.height] stringValue];
    if (tide.height > self.averageTideHeight)
    {
        tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"HW";
    }
    else
    {
        tidalTideTableCell.hwlwTideLabel.text = @"LW";
    }
    tidalTideTableCell.timeTideLabel.text = tide.date;
    tidalTideTableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return tidalTideTableCell;
}
```

I hope this makes sense - please ask if it's not... I just don't understand why it's ok for the first 1 sets of data and then not for the next 5...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was resolved by calling [UICollectionView refreshdata] in the dequeue method for the mother (outer) UICollectionView

Comment: Have you had problem in managing selections when using this design?

Comment: Hi... The collection view(s) i use don't have the functionality to make selections - they display a table of data. One word of advice would be to make sure the the delegates you are using are set up properly and are propagating correctly (depending on where you act upon the user selection.)

Comment: Indeed. It is tricky. In order to get the correct rendering of selections, one has to handle it in the outmost/parent collection view.

Comment: What dequeue method are you referring to? Can you paste yours in the answer for reference? Sorry I know this is like years later...

Comment: Wasted so much time on this issue. And yet the solution was so simple :|